# DropdownList with Multi select option?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DropDownList as following

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRoles" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Width="150px">
<asp:ListItem Value="9" Text=""></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="0">None</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Ranu</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">Mohit</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="3">Kabeer</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="4">Jems</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="5">Jony</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="6">Vikky</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="7">Satish</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="8">Rony</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I want to select Multiple name at once suppose I want to select Ranu Mohit or Ranu Kabeer Vikky, How its possible?

Comment: Use ListBox instead of DropDownList.

Comment: Not possible unless you make your own custom dropdown, how about using a Listbox ?

Answer (score 1):

[`asp:DropDownList` does not support multiple selects:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist)

> `VerifyMultiSelect()`:
> Always throws an HttpException exception because multiple selection is not supported for the DropDownList control.

You can use `asp:ListBox` with `SelectionMode="Multiple"` instead:

```
<asp:ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" ID="lbRoles" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Width="150px">
    <asp:ListItem Value="9" Text=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">None</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Ranu</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Mohit</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Kabeer</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Jems</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5">Jony</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="6">Vikky</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="7">Satish</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="8">Rony</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```