# asp.net: combobox or listbox PLUS checkbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, telerik

i need a solution like this:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/checkboxes/defaultcs.aspx

however, i need the user to be able to add entries in here.

does such a control already exist?

it can be either jquery or asp.net

it also does not have to be a combobox, it can be a listbox. i need to have every item have a checkbox next to it and be able to add a comment for each entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the ASPxGridLookup control from the DevExpress component vendor.

The ASPxGridLookup component allows the implementation of the multi-select DropDown functionality:

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/ASPxGridLookup/MultiSelect.aspx

http://www.devexpress.com/example=E3467

http://codecentral.devexpress.com/E3467/

with editing capabilities via the embedded ASPxGridView object:

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/EditModes.aspx

Comment: have an easy fast and great new year
!

Answer (score 1):

Ref : [DropdownList with Multi select option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564302/dropdownlist-with-multi-select-option/7564406)

Multiple dropdownlist with checkbox....checkout below link...

checkout demo page here...

http://download.ysatech.com/ASP-NET-Multiple-Selection-DropDownList/ASP-NET-Multiple-Selection-DropDownList.aspx

Blog page here....

http://blog.ysatech.com/post/2009/09/09/ASP-NET-Multiple-Selection-DropDownList-with-AJAX-HoverMenuExtender.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/MultiSelectDropdownList.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like it might be better for you to run with a ListBox. Telerik offers the [**RadListBox**](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx), which allows you to have checkboxes as seen [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/functionality/checkboxes/defaultcs.aspx).

Additionally, you could allow for edits upon, for example, double-click as is displayed in the source code attached to [this forum post](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/listbox/radlistbox-edit-item-in-place.aspx#1441695).

Finally, if you want to also display the comments then you could use an [ItemTemplate](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/functionality/templates/defaultcs.aspx) to define a custom layout for each RadListBoxItem and allow the user to edit both the main and comment fields.

That should cover everything that you need.